# How do I get watir-webdriver to start Firefox 4 with Firebug?

Tags: firefox, firebug, watir-webdriver, firefox4

Any ideas?  I've tried setting webdriver.firefox.useExisting=true as described in the link below hoping to reuse an existing window with firebug enabled, but no such luck.

http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FirefoxDriver

Comment: Good question I was just wondering how you did that myself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you have to create a specific profile where Firebug is always enabled, then launch firefox with this profile in your configuration

Answer (score 5):

The quick answer is:

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new(:firefox, :profile => "default")
```

But if you are running tests you probably shouldn't use the default profile.

Comment: The longer answer is on the wiki page for the WebDriver Ruby bindings: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/RubyBindings#Adding_an_extension

Answer (score 1):

```
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
profile.add_extension "/path/to/firebug.xpi"
browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox, :profile => profile
```