# Does anyone have or know where can I find good documentation on Watir-Webdriver?

Tags: ruby, watir, firewatir, browser-automation, watir-webdriver

I am trying to get my automated test scripts switched over to the watir-webdriver.
Unfortunately I have been unable to completely do so, what I am looking for is a way to drive my web browser and still include add-ons and such. Right now it runs using non of the above.

Does anyone have or know where I can find good documentation on Watir-Webdriver?

Comment: What parts are you having problems with?

Comment: For some reason when I startup my script it pulls a web browser for firefox(the main browser I test) and it does not have any of my add ons attached to the browser. If I fire up firefox normally everything works fine. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: By default it starts up with a clean profile in Firefox. Search on here and there should be questions and answers about including your addons or choosing a different profile.

Comment: Here's the question about changing your profile settings http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6065092/how-do-i-get-watir-webdriver-to-start-firefox-4-with-firebug

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could have a look at the API: http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/watir

Also there are a couple of Google groups for Watir and Watir-webdriver that I have found useful.

Answer (score 3):

There is a new site just launched: http://watirwebdriver.com

Answer (score 1):

Yep, watirmelon.com is also a great site by Alister Scott.  When searching for specific Watir questions in Google, the most useful links are often at watirmelon.com, even for things specific to watir-webdriver.

Also, there's some great documentation at http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/Project+Home and you can find Zeljko's Filipin's Watir book in progress there.  For the most part, what works for Watir will work for watir-webdriver, so you can also use the YARD documentation of the Watir API at http://wtr.rubyforge.org/rdoc/1.6.5/  Good luck.